# NightwatchJS: How to check if attribute is not present?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I want to check if a `disabled` attribute is **not** present on a `button` using NightwatchJS.

I tried doing these:

- `.assert.attributeContains('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', 'null')`
- `.assert.attributeContains('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', null)`
- `.assert.attributeContains('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', 'false')`
- `.assert.attributeContains('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', false)`

But these don't seem to work like they do to check if `disabled` is set to `true` like so:

- `.assert.attributeContains('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', 'true')`

This works just fine! Any idea what's happening here? The error I get is rather cryptic:

`Element does not have a disabled attribute.  - expected "null" but got: null`

Comment: I have the exact same problem. What I'm currently doing is `.assert.elementNotPresent('.phone-verify-btn[disabled]')`, but I also would like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

In this case,I think you should get attribute first until we have better solution. This one works for me :

```
 Browser.getAttribute('@element','disabled',function(result){
   if(result.value === 'true'){
      // element is disabled , do what you want
   }
   // element not disabled .
  })
```

Perhaps it is not really logical !

Comment: I am currently doing something of that sort, but was looking for a clean solution

Comment: Does this help? Slightly cleaner... `Browser.getAttribute('@element','disabled',function(result){
   this.assert.equal(result.value,null) // element not present
  })`

Answer (score 1):

Change attributeContains to attributeEquals

```
.assert.attributeEquals('.phone-verify-btn', 'disabled', null)
```